# Add "shortcode" drop down to WYGWAM

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, drop-down

Looking to build a Wordpress inspired "shortcode" for my EE editors to insert stylized content since they can't design their way out of paper bag. I'd like to put these shortcodes into a dropdown on my WYGWAM editors. Basically just a drop-down list that would paste in a series of Global EE variables into the editor instance.

Example:

```
[DROP DOWN]
-----------
1 Column (value would paste in something like: {column1} Put your info here {/column1}

2 Column

3 Column

4 Column
```

I know I likely need to dive into the CKEditor config.js and link to a new plugin of some sort. Did some searching and found something someone is working on for CKEditor 4, but not sure what that is going to do with WYGWAM and I believe they are still using CK3.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ShortCode](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortcode)? I haven't used it yet myself, but the developer is rock solid and provides excellent support for his other addons.

Comment: I have, yes. I actually just posted on their forum to see if it's possible to integrate into WYGWAM. We'll see what they say. Right now I'm messing with the CKEditor config.js with a plugin.